# How do I fetch data based on user id using Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade, eloquent, userid

I have models User and Diares set up with the hasMany and BelongTo relstionship. I'm trying to fetch data from the  Diaries table associated with a particular user. I tried auth but it didnt work for me. How can i achieve that and display it in the blade view as well. Here is my current code:

```
public function index(User $id)
    {
      $user = User::find($id);
    $record =  $user->diary;


      return view('home')->with('record', $record);

    }
```

The blade file it should display to:

```
 @foreach ($record as $diary)
    {{ $diary->error }}
      {{ $diary->fix }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: what does print_r($user) gives?

Comment: on php artisan tinker or where should i input this

Comment: Well, you can always use **first** instead of **find** https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: inside your index function to check if the user object is passing

Comment: @Exprator when i do it inside index, it shows something like "Property [diary] does not exist on this collection instance"

Comment: what are you getting in the output? and what is diary? is that a function in your model? do post so that we can understand

Comment: @Exprator Diary is a model, it has a corresponding diaries table that contains rows named errors and fix. I want to be able to fetch these rows by user_id. Like, fetch the corresponding rows for a particular user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index function the $id is not integer - this is a User instance, so you can try use this:

```
public function index(User $user)
{
  $record =  $user->diary;

  return view('home')->with('record', $record);

}
```

Comment: and in your routes you should change route to /index/{user}

Comment: thanks @Denis Gorgul. It doesn't throw any error but it doesn't display any records either. I'm confused. OK, i just saw the comment about routes changing.

Comment: I get NotFound HTTP exception. My routes is something like Route::get('/home{user}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Comment: did you forget to put "/" after /home ?
it should be Route::get('/home/{user}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Comment: Thank u so much, it works. I think I can continue from here. Thanks! :))

Comment: it's my pleasure :)